# Magento does not change category photo/thumbnail in existing category

Tags: image, magento

I have almost finished my magento eshop and now that I'm trying to put images to my categories, magento does not change them. I have many categories that now are displayed with the default image. I try to change the image in the category (in different sizes, from 300x300px to 50x50px) , magento says that the category is successfully saved but then the image does not appear in the frontend.

NOTE that I have disabled cache so this is not the reason.

Note2: I'm using "TM Easy Catalog Images" but still this is not the p0roblem, I disabled it and still have the same issue.

Note 3: Magento used is : 1.7.0.2 running on local pc for now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found. I had to "chmod -R 777 media" directory.